# Legend icons in Winter Bash profile dialog are too responsive

Tags: bug, status-completed, responsive-design, winter-bash-2022

There are some icons in the legend of the Winter Bash profile dialog:

[image]

I *assume* they're meant to remain square at all times, yet they don't (and look suboptimal) at narrow screen sizes, especially the "Currently selected hat":

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fine..... I guess we can make them slightly less responsive. Fixed!

[image]